# Table like data structure for query handling and mathematical operations

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to have a table like representation of data with multiple columns. e.g. consider following sample:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5(numeric)    col6(numeric)
---------------------------------------------------------------
val01   val02   val03   val04        05               06
val11   val12   val13   val14        15               16
val21   val22   val23   val24        25               26
val31   val32   val33   val34        35               36
.
.
.
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to query on this table by a value in given col e.g. search for value `val32` in column `col2` which should return me all rows that could match this query in the same tabular format.

for some columns like say `col5` and `col6`, I'd like to perform mathematical operations/queries like `getMax()`, `getMin()`, `getSum()`, `divideAll()` etc...

For such requirement can anybody suggest any type of data structure that could best solve my purpose? Any one data structure or combination of them, Considering efficient operations (like mathematical examples above), and querying??

Let me know if anybody need more information.

`Edit: Additional requirement`

This should be efficient enough to handle hundreds of millions of rows and also easy and efficient to persist.

Comment: Have you tried the most naive approach; an array of arrays. Maybe it's good enough?

Comment: I thought there could be some more intelligent ways available to solve such problem, instead of going into very basic implementations..

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a three-part approach:

1. A `Row` class that contains fields for each column
2. A `List<Row>` to store the rows and provide sequential access
3. One or more `Map<String,Row>` or `Map<Integer,Row>` to provide fast lookup of the rows by various column values.  If the column values are not unique then you need a `MultiMap<...>` implementation (there are several available on the Internet) to allow multiple values for a given key.

The `Row` objects are first placed in the list, and then you build the index(es) after you have loaded all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think below should help:

```
Map<String,List<Object>>
```

1. Search "val32" in "col2", search(cal2,val32):

get the list of the objects associated with cal2(map.get("cal2"),and iterate over them to find if this value exists or not.

1. getSum(String columnName):

Again just get the list, iterate over it add these values. Return the final sum.

Since you are adding List of Objects, you might want to throw ClassCasteException from these APIs.

Comment: what should be the `String` in `Map`? and what should go to `list`?

Comment: String would be the column name and List will have all the entries in the column.

Comment: As per your question, column can have Integers or String values, thats why i take Object so that you can have anytype in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I planned to use Mongo Database instead of going through all basic and complicated implementations..

I hope this will solve my problem. Or there is any other db better that this in terms of speed, storage, and availability of required operations (as mentioned in question)?

Comment: Because of heavy write operations requirement, I found that mongodb is not suitable.